# how to get text from a dynamic table in wtforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to create a flask form where data is dynamically added.

I have this table where its columns are inputs, and the last one is an 'add' button which adds the inputs into a new row. And I have to get the data in those rows into flask form with wtforms.

The following is just an example of what my problem is, but I have different inputs.

Here is an example HTML where the user added the first name

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><label>name</label><input type="text"></td>
            <td><label>age</label><input type="number"></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="addRow">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I want the names as a list and their corresponding ages as a list. But I don't know what form field I can use if its possible,

Comment: To be sure that I understood correctly, what is the interest for you of using the Wtforms here?

Comment: This is part of a form where I get other data. In this table, I have to get all the entries in the rows. the problem is I don't know how many rows the user will add that's why we thought of using this type of table.

If Wtforms isn't the solution here what do you suggest?